# ui.bootstrap.datepicker is-open not working second time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using ui.bootstrap.datepicker , for first click it is working and second click onwards it is not working.

I used many options like  `is-open='$parent.isOpen'` and `ng-model="$parent.date ="` and `$timeOut service` nothing work for me.

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="myDate" is-open="$parent.isOpen"  />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCalendar($event, prop)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't just put `is-open="isOpen"` and `ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen"`?

Answer (score 1):

This solution works, the problem is the $scope.

HTML

```
<input ng-click="openDatepicker($event)" type="text" class="form-control"

datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" ng-model="submission.require_date"

is-open="mydp.opened" min-date="minDate" datepicker-options="dateOptions"

ng-required="true" close-text="Close">
```

Js snippet

```
$scope.openDatepicker = function($event) {
   $event.preventDefault();
   $event.stopPropagation();
   if (typeof($scope.mydp) === 'undefined'){
       $scope.mydp = {};
   }
   $scope.mydp.opened = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This typically occurs due to binding to a primitive and prototypal inheritance as described [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).  You will see quite often developers will create a 'vm' object in their controller and bind to that

```
$scope.vm = $scope;
$scope.isOpen = false;

<input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="myDate" is-open="vm.isOpen"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I got it working by wrapping the configs in an object rather than binding to directly scope.

```
$scope.datePickerSetting = {
  dateOptions: {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
  },
  format: 'dd/MM/yyyy',
  opened: false
};
```

And then

```
<input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker-input" ng-model="dob" datepicker-popup="{{datePickerSetting.format}}" is-open="datePickerSetting.opened" datepicker-options="datePickerSetting.dateOptions" close-text="Close" readonly="readonly" ng-blur="closeDatepicker()" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code using jquery 1.11,

CSHTML Code:

```
@Html.TextBox("FirstContactDate", "", new { @autocomplete="off"})
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FirstContactDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        selectedMonth: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
        }
    });
    $("#FirstContactDate").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: if you re focusing an individual item, why show all the calendars by class?? Did you ever test this code??